# How to make fan-out akka-streams processing concurrent

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, akka-stream

I'm attempting to use Akka Streams to concurrently process a series of dependent streams.

Something like this:

```
val concurrency = 2
Source(
  (1 to 5).toStream.map(i => {
    println(s"1: Emitting $i")
    i.toString
  }))
  .mapAsyncUnordered(concurrency)(s => getNextStream(s, 25))
  .mapConcat(identity)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(concurrency)(out => getNextStream(out.x, 50))
  .mapConcat(identity)
  .mapAsyncUnordered(concurrency)(out => getNextStream(out.x, 100))
  .mapConcat(identity)
  .map(x => println(s"4: Received $x after ${System.currentTimeMillis() - start}"))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

My problem is it doesn't appear to be running concurrently. Changing the `concurrency` variable has no effect beyond `2`. I suspect that `mapConcat` is serializing the processing but I'm not sure.

A full, runnable example of the problem can be found here: https://github.com/realrunner/akka-stream-example.

Currently, the code takes 11 seconds to complete. I could easily cut it down using raw Actors, without the benefit of properly handling backpressure. Any ideas on how to make this more concurrent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each and every one of these `getNextStream` calls go out and use `ask` against one single(ton) actor. Keep in mind an actor processes incoming messages in a serialized manner.

Now when processing the message, you block the actor by using `Thread.sleep`. Blocking is generally discouraged within Akka - see this bit of the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#blocking-needs-careful-management).

Depending on what is the real behaviour of your actors, you can simulate long processing in a non-blocking way using the `after` pattern (see [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/futures.html#after)), or if blocking is *really* needed - but double, triple check that - you can block on a dedicated dispatcher (as explained [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/dispatchers.html#solution-dedicated-dispatcher-for-blocking-operations)).